# Can browse to an app at localhost.company.com but that isn't in /etc/hosts; where else could the redirection be?

Tags: osx, ip, webserver, hosts

```
✗ cat /etc/hosts
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
✗
```

But I'm browsing to an app (my app that I'm building/running/coding) at `http://localhost.company.com:8080/help`.

Checked `cat /private/etc/hosts` and it matches `/etc/hosts`.

So where else can I look for this `localhost.company.com` redirection?

Comment: localhost is not localhost.domain

Comment: Check dns - ping localhost.company.com, and see the ip

Comment: but I know that it's running on my machine -- I started the app that's listening on that port (updated question)

Comment: What is your hostname fqdn? Is it possible it’s localhost.company?

Comment: Your company might have a DNS record for `localhost.company.com` pointing at 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Dani_l the ping resolves to my machine

Comment: And what exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer elsewhere. The nslookup tool:

> nslookup is a network administration command-line tool available for many computer operating systems for querying the Domain Name System (DNS) to obtain domain name or IP address mapping or for any other specific DNS record.

So, running that for localhost tells me that (I think) localhost.company.com is mapped to everyone's local machine at the DNS level.

```
✗ nslookup  
> localhost
Server:     x.x.x.x
Address:    x.x.x.x#x

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   localhost.company.com
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I'm even getting downvoted on the answer, wtf

Comment: You're getting downvoted (not by me, FWIW) because Dani_l and DopeGhoti told you *exactly* what to look for, and now you're here claiming that you found the answer elsewhere. ***And***  because you're just dumping a command and its output, without any explanation.

Comment: I answered Dani's question. DopeGhoti didn't tell me how I could check for that -- which appears to be the answer but since they didn't actually create an answer...

Comment: I've amended my answer. It seems rude to downvote people for not responding to every comment or whatever.